# Updating leaflet circle marker AND deleting previous ones

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am very new to JS. I have a circle marker that displays my current location and I want the circle to update constantly so it could track my location when I move.

I have managed to create this in Leaflet but now I get circles and the screen gets full of them. I have used map.removeLayer, but it is not working. This is the code I have:

```
<script>
    
    var zoom = 13;

    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
    console.log('geolocation available');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lat, lon);

        var map = L.map('mapid').setView([lat, lon], zoom);

        var circle = L.circle([lat, lon]).addTo(map)

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        setInterval(function() {
            if (circle) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    lon = position.coords.longitude;
                    map.removeLayer(circle);
                })
                circle = new L.circleMarker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);
            }
        }, 1000);
    
    });
    } else {
    console.log('geolocation not available');
    }
    


</script>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want `L.circleMarker` or `L.circle`? You seem to be using both.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#circlemarker-setlatlng

Comment: You also have an async mess up there - `lat` and `lon` are not being updated when you think they are. You're waiting to delete circles but not to create them, and there's a race condition between `setInterval` and the geolocation requests.

Comment: @IvanSanchez, would you be able to give me a more specific suggestion? Sorry I am very new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint:

```js
map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
    console.log("Marker found to remove: ");
    console.log(layer);
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  } else {
    console.log("No Marker found");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) function to continuously track your GPS position. Move all the creation of the map and stuff that doesn't have to update outside of the `watchPosition` function.

Inside the success callback, check if the `marker` already exists. If it doesn't, then create it first and add it to the map. Otherwise just update the marker by settings it's `LatLng`.

```
const zoom = 13;
const map = L.map('mapid');
let marker = null;

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

    if (marker === null) {
      marker = L.circleMarker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);
    }

    marker.setLatLng([latitude, longitude]);
  });
} else {
  console.log('geolocation not available');
}
```